# Real-Time multiplayer: EDIT: How to smooth out animation frames on Canvas

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am trying to build a real-time multiplayer app. For this, I am using React, Node.js and Socket.io. After deploying it to Heroku I discovered my problem. If I visit it from the Laptop I developed it from it works like a charm. Everything is displayed according to the inputs from both 
 me and my opponent. On other devices, however, all objects that are drawn on the canvas go nuts. It makes no difference if the devices are in the same network or not.

The users are supposed to enter a socket.io room. First they meet in a chat and after clicking ready they are immediately send to the GameRoom where the game starts right away.

I highly appreciate any kind of input or hint! If you have no answer ready but have input on how to improve my question in order to help people to understand my problem feel free to comment.

First I changed the way socket.io emits the current gamestate to the room via `socket.volatile.to(room).emit()`. I thought it would optimise the handling of the server messages. This didn´t help.

Then I adjusted the way the game is drawn on the client side. The draw logic on the client side is now similar to that on the server side, but that did not help either.

That is why I think that the way I draw the game is not the problem here.

I am a part of a bootcamp and all my fellow students use the same MacBook as I do. If I want to play against them, their game is not displayed properly but mine is. Hence, i conclude that is not the Hardware.

I erased all .env variables. Therefore this too should not be the problem. I am out of Ideas.

This is my Client-Side code for the socket:

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

export default function Main({ setSettings, settings }) {
  const [connectedTo, setConnectionTo] = React.useState({});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io();
    socket.emit("setname", getItem("nickname"));
    setConnectionTo({ connected: true, socket, player: false });
    return () => {
      socket.close();
      setConnectionTo(false);
    };
  }, [connectedTo.room]);
```

This is the client-side draw-loop. It is in another component and gets the socket via props:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let currentFrame;
    let canvas = canvasRef.current;
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const drawLoop = () => {
      const now = Date.now();
      const timeSinceLastDraw = game.global.lastDraw
        ? now - game.global.lastDraw
        : 0;
      game.global.lastDraw = now;

      const newGameState = calculateNewGameStateClient(game, 
      timeSinceLastDraw);
      const { ball, player1, player2, global } = newGameState;

      drawGameState(ctx, global, ball, player1, player2);

      if (game.global.play) {
        currentFrame = requestAnimationFrame(() => drawLoop());
      }
    };
    if (game && game.global.play !== "ended") {
      drawLoop();
    }
    return () => cancelAnimationFrame(currentFrame);
  }, [game]);
```

This is the server-side socket:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const PORT = 5000;

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/build", "index.html"));
});

const server = app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`));

initSocket(server);
```

This is the server-side draw-loop:

```
    function drawLoop(game) {
      const now = Date.now();
      const timeSinceLastDraw = game.global.lastDraw
        ? now - game.global.lastDraw
        : 0;
      game.global.lastDraw = now;
      const newGameState = calculateNewGameStateServer(
        game,
        io,
        room,
        timeSinceLastDraw
      );
      if (game.global.play) {
        updateTime += timeSinceLastDraw;
        if (updateTime > 100) {
          io.to(room).emit("new frame", newGameState);
          updateTime = 0;
        }
        setTimeout(() => drawLoop(newGameState), 0);
      } else {
        const player1Won = game.player2.lifes === 0;
        game.global.winner = player1Won ? "1" : "2";
        game.global.lastDraw = 0;
        socket.emit("game ended", game);
      }
    }
```

EDIT: I erased the client-side draw-loop. Now it´s laggy but it works! I will review other peoples questions and edit this question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to figure out why it was working on one specific machine. A friend told me to try incognito mode as it supposably ignores the cache. However, the main problem seems to be the client side loop. As this is a totally different question which has many answers here I think this question can be viewed as "answered".

e.g. : [Smooth Canvas Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589187/smooth-canvas-animation)